# select * from a,b where a.id=b.id VS select * from a inner join b on a.id=b.id

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have the SQL for postgres:

```
select * from a,b where a.id=b.id
```

and I get the same length of rows (answers) and columns in the next sql:

```
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
```

I'm really confuse for this. a from a,b is a implicit INNER JOIN ?

Comment: Yes, it is an older syntax for joining tables.

Comment: Are you recommend from a,b or inner join?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is more widely accepted now.